# PostgreSQL 9.3 is not returning existing rows with Ruby on Rails or Squirrel

Tags: postgresql

I dumped an existing PostgrSQL database (generating "Insert" statements), and imported it on another computer. The source runs Debian (UK) OS, the target Mint (FR) OS.

For some tables, when I try to visualise in Squirrel SQL, I get the following:

- Squirrel "Row count" tab displays 351
- Squirrel "Content" does not show anything
- but executing the query "select * from myTable" returns all the lines

For the same table, when ruby tries to extract one record, it does not find it. But I can check that the record exists in Squirrel.

All indexes were rebuilt, no transaction pending. 
The same data base is accessed with Ruby and Squirrel, with the same user.

What could be the reason, how to solve this blocking issue ?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: What exactly does "*Content does not show anything*" mean? Most of the time in cases like this the answer is: you are connected to different databases in Squirrel and Ruby

Answer (score 0):

The source of the issue was the name of one colunm of the table: PCF_index

psql generated "PCF_index" when exporting the schema. This caused trouble to Squirrel when trying to read it.

After the column is renamed pcf_index, the issue was solved.

Comment: About double-quoted identifiers: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34109/3684, and why it's better not to use them in Postgres: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860