# is camel case for column names safe?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a database where column names are all camel cased. No problems encountered.
Will that be a problem under some scenarios, as per recent versions of MySQL, Postgres?

Comment: It depends: `select ThisIsAColumnName from SomeTable` is the same as `select thisisacolumnanme from sometable` (according to the SQL standard) . This is true for all Postgres versions. On MySQL this depends the storage engine used, the MySQL and storage engine configuration and the file system that is used. I personally prefer `snake_case` over `CamelCase` in SQL - but that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

The only cases I can think of for MySQL where case sensitivity could be an issue would be

- Case #1 : Data Dictionary entries for tables by table_name (See my post [Is it okay to have different lower_case_table_names value on master and slave?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35632/is-it-okay-to-have-different-lower-case-table-names-value-on-master-and-slave/35686#35686))
- Case #2 : Migrating InnoDB tables with referential constraints from Linux to Windows (see my posts [MySQL case sensitivity for table names](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/mysql-case-sensitivity-for-table-names/34113#34113) and [Is it possible to use the same directory for 2 MySQL servers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31551/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-directory-for-2-mysql-servers/31562#31562))

In those cases, the table name can cause problems. As for column names, it should not be an issue.

Comment: Case #3: When you use an ORM based application (which uses camel/pascal case usually) and every time you migrate & generate code using the database schema, you need to convert every field name from snake_case to Camel/Pascal case (hundreds of fields), kind of breaks the point of ORMs.